# Bee Identification, Rochester NY

Tags: species-identification, entomology

bee I found in Rochester NY, any guesses what species? [image]

Comment: Some kind of Halictidae. You can tell by the pollen-collecting ventral side of the abdomen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bee in the genus *Megachile*, in the family Megachilidae, not Halictidae.

[Megachile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megachile) are leafcutter bees, and have scopal (pollen carrying) hairs on their bellies (ventral side of their abdomen).

Most bees in the family [Halictidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halictidae) have scopae for carrying pollen on their legs, though they may have hairy bellies with substantial pollen carrying capacity.